# Generating a single include file from a hierarchy of includes

Tags: c++, packaging

I have a C++ repository for a header-only library (built via CMake, although that's not critical). Its structure is roughly:

```
include/
  mylib.hpp
  mylib/
    foo.hpp
    bar.hpp
```

Now, I know some popular C++ libraries are maintained as single-header files. I don't like dumping everything into a kitchen-sink file; but at the same time I can well appreciate the convenience of being able to utilize a library by just downloading a single file.

So, I was thinking - maybe I can just *generate* the single header file as part of the installation process?

Supposedly this is a "simple matter of prerocessing"; but - it's not actually quite that simple:

- I don't want to fully preprocess the C++ files, just `#include` directives.
- Not all include files are relevant - only the files under a certain source tree.
- During actual compilation, the same file is included multiple times (ignoring potential compiler optimizations against doing so), with the second-and-later copies typically removed later using include guards or `#pragma once`; in my case one would need to watch out and prevent double includes.

So, my question: How do I go about doing this?

Note:

- A CMake-based method would be nice, but anything reasonable goes.

Comment: I think GoogleTest has something similar, see if it suits you: [`fuse_gtest_files.py`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/release-1.8.0/googletest/scripts/fuse_gtest_files.py) (lines 149-175 seem to be responsible for header file generation)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: I'll have a look, thanks. I actually have an answer of my own but now I can't post it since I got closed. Grrr.

Comment: Libraries at least expand the functionality of the host language (see that Yksis comment is for compacting headers **and source**). Your headers would functionally be boilerplate of includes, just that users don't know what they are including (or if it's everything necessary). (btw, I use my system package manager for everything, so this comment is obviously very biased)

Comment: @Braiam: They are including the mylib header-only library. I'm not sure I understand your point.

Answer (score -1):

You could just code yourself a parser. You give it the beginning file. It replaces all `#include`s with the actual file. If the file to be included was already included, skip it (similar to how compiler behaves towards include guards)

Comment: So, I actually just found a (bit of an ugly) [parser](https://github.com/bfgroup/Lyra/blob/develop/tools/gen_single_include.py) - but I can't post an answer because they closed my question T_T.

Answer (score -2):

Building on @uIM7AI9S's suggestion - such a mechanism must surely exist in other libraries which want development to happen with multiple files but still offer a single-include-file convenience. One example is [Lyra](https://github.com/bfgroup/Lyra/), a command-line argument parsing library; it uses a Python-based include file fuser/joiner, which you can find [here](https://github.com/bfgroup/Lyra/blob/develop/tools/gen_single_include.py).

I could nitpick at the code of that thing, but - hey,  it works and it's FOSS - distributed with the Boost license.

Unfortunately, it seems the Lyra developers pre-generate the single header, and that process is not part of a CMake-based build (despite there being a `CMakeLists.txt` file in the repository's root)